# Integrating the js code in R to make the visNetwork edges curved

Tags: javascript, arrays, r, vis.js, visnetwork

the script below creates the visNetwork as shown in the visualization below. I want a functionality to make the edge "1" and edge "3" curved. I am attaching the js code that can be used to achieve this. However, please help me to integrate the same code in R. Thanks.

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,4,3,2), to = c(1,2,4,3), label = 1:4)
edges <- data.frame(edges,edges$from)
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
visEdges(arrows =list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 2)),
       color = list(color = "lightblue", highlight = "red")) %>% 
visHierarchicalLayout()
```

**JS Code**

```
{from: 2, to: 1, arrows: 'to', label: "1", smooth: {type: "curvedCCW", 
roundness: 0.4}},
{from: 3, to: 4, arrows: 'to', label: "3", smooth: {type: "curvedCCW", 
roundness: 0.2}},
```

[image: Visnetwork Capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code with listed paramaters of `smooth`:

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:4)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,4,3,2), to = c(1,2,4,3), label = 1:4, smooth = list(enabled = F, type ='curvedCW', roundness = 0.2))
edges <- data.frame(edges,edges$from)

#enable smooth for the edges you like

edges$smooth.enabled[edges$label==1] = T
edges$smooth.enabled[edges$label==3] = T
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
  visEdges(arrows =list(to = list(enabled = TRUE, scaleFactor = 2)),
           color = list(color = "lightblue", highlight = "red")) %>% 
  visHierarchicalLayout()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Kindly help me with this post here regarding R shiny, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48185330/increasing-the-height-of-the-daterangeinput-and-alignment-in-r-shiny