# Increasing the height of the DateRangeInput and alignment in R shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I need the following requirement with the **R** script below. When you click on the sidebar symbol at the top, when dashboard body expands, all widgets are in one line, however when the dashboard body shrinks, the `dateRangeInput` widget appears in the below line. I want all widgets to appear in one line and resize accordingly. Please help and thanks.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
box(title = "Data", fluidPage(

  div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 600 px;", 
selectInput("select1","select1",c("A1","A2","A3")),selected = "A1"),
  div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 600 px;", 
selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5")),selected = "A3"),
  div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 600 px;", 
selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5")),selected = "A3"),
  div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 600 px;", 
selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5")),selected = "A3"),
div(style = "display: inline-block;vertical-align:top; width: 600 px;",   
dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:",

start = "2001-01-01",

end   = "2010-12-31")
),
status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12, height = 120)
)
))
server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Snapshot Capture]

Comment: I have fixed the height issue of the daterangebar using tags$style.Please help me to fix the resize issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your code was off such that one didnt even see the box around your inputs.

Besides that: You're somewhat styled divs were not useful in achieving what you desired. Feel free to browse through the [shiny layout guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) section on the *Fluid Grid* to explore what possibilities in styling you have by just using the right functions shiny offers.

For the height issue in daterange widgets: The selects have a min-height of 34 pixels. If you also apply that to daterange objects by css, you can have them be the same size.

Corrected code below:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Data", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, width = 12,
      fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
          column(2, selectInput("select1","select1",c("A1","A2","A3"), selected = "A1")),
          column(2, selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5"), selected = "A3")),
          column(2, selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5"), selected = "A3")),
          column(2, selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5"), selected = "A3")),
          column(4, dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Date range:", start = "2001-01-01",end = "2010-12-31")),
          tags$head(
            tags$style("
              .input-daterange input {
                min-height: 34px;
              }
            ")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: kindly help me with this post here, thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337624/using-similar-ui-script-in-r-shiny-under-multiple-submenuitems