# Using similar UI script in R shiny under multiple subMenuItems

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

the given R shiny script creates a dropdown menu in the sidebar with main and sub menu items. When you click on the first sub-item 1, you get two selectInputs in the dashboardBody. I want a functionality where I just declare these inputs once and use it multiple times in the other sub-items, just like how reactive function does.I want to do this to make the script fast and efficient. I have less knowledge of reactive functionality, please help and thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(), 
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(

  id = "tabs",
  menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 3", tabName = "subitem3"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 4", tabName = "subitem4")
        ))),
  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
  tabItem("subitem1", column(2,offset = 0, style='padding:1px;', 
  selectInput("select1","select1",c("A1","A2","A3"), selected = "A1")),
          column(2,offset = 0, style='padding:1px;', 
  selectInput("select2","select2",c("A3","A4","A5"), selected = "A3"))),
  tabItem("subitem2", "Widgets tab content"),
  tabItem("subitem3", "Sub-item 1 tab content"),
  tabItem("subitem4", "Sub-item 2 tab content"))))
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Select Input Capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten with shiny [`modules`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). The UI module where you want to display the two dropdowns can be written as one (Ui function) and then can be referred in the places you want.

Modified code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

submenuUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)


  # return a list of tags
  tagList(
     column(2,offset = 0, style='padding:1px;', 
                               selectInput(ns("select1"),"select1",c("A1","A2","A3"), selected = "A1")),
            column(2,offset = 0, style='padding:1px;', 
                   selectInput(ns("select2"),"select2",c("A3","A4","A5"), selected = "A3"))
  )


}


submenu <- function(input,output,session){}


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(

      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 3", tabName = "subitem3"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 4", tabName = "subitem4")
      ))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem("subitem1", submenuUI('submenu1')),
      tabItem("subitem2", submenuUI('submenu2')),
      tabItem("subitem3", submenuUI('submenu3')),
      tabItem("subitem4", "Sub-item 2 tab content"))))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(submenu, "submenu")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, my small query is, I need to replicate this for 16 subitems, will it give a fast solution?

Comment: @AdamShaw Ideally it should, I guess. Why don't you test it?

Comment: kindly check this post, I am struggling to integrate observe Event with shiny Modules here, kindly check the solution posted too, thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394545/usage-of-uioutput-in-multiple-menuitems-in-r-shiny-dashboard/48394758#48394758