# Using shiny plotOutput in multiple places in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shinyapps

I am trying to use plotOutput in R shiny in multiple sub-menu items. However, I believe it is not possible for plotOutput to be used at multiple places with same id. Please help me if it is possible somehow. attaching the snapshot for reference.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
id = "tabs",
  menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
  ))),
dashboardBody(
tabItems(tabItem("subitem1", 3),
         tabItem("subitem2", plotOutput("brand_selector")))
 ))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$brand_selector <-  renderPlot({
plot(iris$Sepal.Length)
}) 
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: snapshot]

**Update**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
submenuUI <- function(id) {
ns <- NS(id)
# return a list of tags
tagList(
column(2,offset = 0, style='padding:1px;', 

selectInput(ns("select1"),"select1",c("A1","A2","A3","A2","A1","A3","A1"))),
column(2,offset = 0, style='padding:1px;', 

selectInput(ns("select2"),"select2",c("B3","B4","B5","B3","B6","B2","B3")))
)
}
submenu <- function(input,output,session){}
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(), 
dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
id = "tabs",
  menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 3", tabName = "subitem3"),
           menuSubItem("Sub-item 4", tabName = "subitem4")
  ))),
 dashboardBody(
 tabItems(tabItem("subitem1", submenuUI('submenu1')),
         tabItem("subitem2", submenuUI('submenu2')),
         tabItem("subitem3", submenuUI('submenu3')),
         tabItem("subitem4", "Sub-item 2 tab content"))))
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Select1,{
  updateSelectInput(session,'Select2',
                  choices= input$select2[input$Select1 == "A1"] )
   }) 
   callModule(submenu, "submenu")
   }
   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please help me to update the second selectInput based on input from the previous selectInput.

Comment: Maybe this post can help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337624/using-similar-ui-script-in-r-shiny-under-multiple-submenuitems/48338347#48338347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the modularized code for multiple plotting: Very similar to the selectInput one.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

plotopUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)


  # return a list of tags
  tagList(
   plotOutput(ns('plt'))
  )


}



plotop <- function(input,output,session){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$plt <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris$Sepal.Length)
  })
}


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(), 
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(

      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 1", tabName = "subitem1"),
               menuSubItem("Sub-item 2", tabName = "subitem2")
      ))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem("subitem1", plotopUI('plt1')),
             tabItem("subitem2", plotopUI('plt2')))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(plotop, "plt1")
  callModule(plotop, "plt2")
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for relpying here, I shall definitely accept the solution, however as I am progressing ahead in my work, I came to see that, the help I need here is a little different, I have observeEvent function which I am not able to use with shinyModules , please help me with a fix on the same. I regret for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please check the script below the Update, it is  not a new requirement but an addon to what I had asked, the observeEvent is not getting fixed along with shiny modules, I would greatly appreciate your help here.

Comment: @AdamShaw I've to rush out, I'll reply after a few hours.

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it, I have posted an altogether new question and would like you to assist here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385417/automating-selectinput-and-menuitems-in-r-shiny

Comment: I have put my own effort and done furthur simplification of the requirement, please help me here, I am sure this is easy to crack, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394545/usage-of-uioutput-in-multiple-menuitems-in-r-shiny-dashboard

Comment: please help me with this script here based on R shiny Modules, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48496426/display-the-selectinput-value-in-a-r-shiny-widget-box